# Is there an equivalent for the deprecated -ng serve option "vendor-source-map" in Angular 11?

Tags: angular-cli

Updated an older project from Angular 9 to 11 but now I can't debug files from my Angular Library in my Client browser application like I used to with `ng serve --vendorSourceMap`. I'm wondering if their is a equivalent way to access my files from the running application in the browser to debug.

I have tried using the browser builder in the `angular.json` file following the workspace instructions here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config to no luck. Is this just no longer an option in new versions of Angular or is there a trick to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might solve that kind of issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617089/angular-12-library-source-maps-unavailable